# How To Pass Two @RequestBody from Postman (springboot)

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot

My Controller:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1Ndr.png)

postman request body is:

```
[
    {
        "id": "PG"
    },
    {
        "id": "123456"
    }
]
```

Error: [org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `Course` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`); nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize value of type `Course` from Array value (token `JsonToken.START_ARRAY`) at [Source: (org.springframework.util.StreamUtils$NonClosingInputStream);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@RequestBody` annotated parameter is expected to hold the entire body of the request and bind to one object.

What you can do is make a new model such as EnrollmentObject and have the ID of the course and the ID of the student in there. Then, you can have `@RequestBody EnrollmentObject enrollmentObject`.

You should obviously go with another model name, but you get the point! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can define your request body as an array like the following:

```
public ResponseEntity<String> enroll(@RequestBody Course[] courses) {
    // use courses array here
}
```